# Redux-Persist works on all routes/pages/refreshes except for one route/page/refresh on my react project

Tags: reactjs, redux, local-storage, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

In my shopping website project, I have successfully implemented redux with redux-toolkit and am using redux-persist to save the user and cart-items data to storage.
Everything works fine except for a strange bug. Lets say I got to MyCart page and increment the number of a certain item from 10 to 12 and then go to the MyProfile page and refresh the page, amount of item in my cart is 12, which is how it should be.
But if I do the same steps of incrementing a certain item from 10 to 12 in the CartPage and then go to the Home Page and refresh, instead of a cart count of 12 I revert back to 10. Going back to CartPage and adding two more items and refreshing persists the 12 count. Does it make any sense?

My index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <App />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

This is how the store looks like:

```
import {
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  version: 1,
  storage,
  
};

const persistedUserReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, userReducer);
const persistedCartReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, cartReducer);
const persistedPizzasReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, pizzasReducer);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    cart: persistedCartReducer,
    pizzas: persistedPizzasReducer,
    reviews: reviewReducer,
    login: loginReducer,
    user: persistedUserReducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }),
});
```

The cartSlice looks like this. Ignore some of the redundant code. I was experimenting.

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  cartItems: [],
  total: 0,
  items: 0,
  cartAlert: false,
};

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    // Todo: add pizza to cart
    addItemToCart: (state, { payload }) => {
      const newItem = payload;
      const existingItem = state.cartItems.find(
        (item) => item.id === newItem.id && item.varient === newItem.varient
      );

      if (existingItem) {
        if (existingItem.quantity >= 10) {
          alert(`cannot order more than 10 pizzas`);
          return;
        }
        existingItem.quantity = existingItem.quantity + newItem.quantity;
        existingItem.price =
          existingItem.quantity * existingItem.prices[0][existingItem.varient];
      } else {
        state.cartItems.push(newItem);
      }
    },
    // Todo: add one pizza
    addOneItem: (state, { payload }) => {
      const { id, varient } = payload;
      const item = state.cartItems.find(
        (i) => i.id === id && i.varient === varient
      );
      if (item.quantity >= 10) {
        alert(`cannot order more than 10 pizzas`);
        return;
      }
      item.quantity += 1;
      item.price = item.prices[0][varient] * item.quantity;
      state.total += item.prices[0][varient];
    },
    // todo: remove one pizza
    removeOneItem: (state, { payload }) => {
      const { id, varient, index } = payload;
      const item = state.cartItems.find(
        (i) => i.id === id && i.varient === varient
      );
      if (item.quantity > 1) {
        item.quantity -= 1;
        item.price = item.prices[0][varient] * item.quantity;
        state.total -= item.prices[0][varient];
      } else {
        state.cartItems.splice(index, 1);
      }
    },

    //  todo: remove item from cart

    removeAllItem: (state, { payload }) => {
      const { index } = payload;
      state.cartItems.splice(index, 1);
    },

    // todo: get total price
    setTotalPrice: (state) => {
      const total = state.cartItems.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.price, 0);
      state.total = total;
    },
    // todo: get total item count
    setCartCount: (state) => {
      const count = state.cartItems.reduce(
        (sum, item) => sum + item.quantity,
        0
      );
      state.items = count;
    },

    // todo: reset cart
    resetCart: (state) => {
      state.cartItems = [];
      state.total = 0;
      state.items = 0;
    },

    // todo: show and hide alert popup
    showAlert: (state) => {
      state.cartAlert = true;
    },
    hideAlert: (state) => {
      state.cartAlert = false;
    },

    // todo: clear all items from cart
    clearFullCart: (state) => {
      state.cartItems = [];
      return state;
    },
  },
});

export const {
  addItemToCart,
  setCartCount,
  setTotalPrice,
  addOneItem,
  removeOneItem,
  removeAllItem,
  resetCart,
  showAlert,
  hideAlert,
  clearFullCart,
} = cartSlice.actions;

export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: Do you have the same problem when incrementing from 5 to 7?  I'm noticing that you've got some behavior to cap quantities at 10 and I'm not sure if that is part of it.

Comment: IMO it's worth trying combining the reducers with `combineReducers` first, and then calling `persistReducer` on the combined version, using the `blacklist` or `whitelist` to determine which reducers to include.  But I can't guarantee that this will fix anything because I don't know what the problem is.  I would double check that you are not mutating the Redux state in any of your components, because that could explain the buggy behavior.